How to find auto approve comment available blogs in search
How can I find auto approve comments avilable sites in search for my blog
about Bangladesh?

It sounds a lot like you just asked "where can I spam?" which might not be something site admins are likely to feel too happy about. You might want to ask this in some sort of SEO forum that is permissive about sketchy SEO.
